# Access view fields inside page--%.html.twig

Tags: drupal, twig, themes

I have a view named "Blog archive". The view displaye title, blurb and image fields. It's a page view and the twig template for the view is named as "page--blog--archive.html.twig". The view content is as follows:

```
 {% if page.content %}
   {{ page.content }}
 {% endif %}
```

Thsi prints out the view fields correctly but without any style classes. I want to add the below snippet into the twig template and iterate through view rows:

```
   <div class="grid-4 omega ft-text">
     <h3 class="blog-title"><a href="{{ fields.title.content|striptags}}">{{ fields.title.content }}</a> </h3>
     <br/>
     <span style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;">
     <p>{{ fields.field_blurb_new.content }}</p>
     </span>
<h4><a href="{{ field_blog_readmore_link|striptags}}">{{fields.field_blog_readmore_link.content }}</a></h4>
</div>
```

any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: Turn on twig debug on your services.yml file, then using inspect tool you should be able to see which file is rendering that snippet. I'm guessing you should be able to find it within your-theme/templates/fields