# How to access view fields inside page--%.html.twig

Tags: drupal, twig

I have a page view that displays title and body fields and the twig template for the view is named as "page--my--view.html.twig". The view content is as follows:

```
 {% if page.content %}
   {{ page.content }}
 {% endif %}
```

How can I add individual fields and classes in this template? For example:

```
<h3 class="title"><a href="{{ fields.title.content|striptags}}">{{ fields.title.content }}</a> </h3>
```

I want to add a 'for' loop and print all the titles through page template like above. How to do this?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710259/access-view-fields-inside-page-html-twig